# jQuery - how to refresh selectors after adding a class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've made this example in jsfiddle to demonstrate my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/paulmason411/7E6vG/

See how the grey class is added and yet it doesn't apply the left margin when u hover a second time. I'm guessing this is because the `$('.block.grey')` selector is declared before the class is grey class is added.

Is there anyway I can get the `$('.block.grey')` selector to re-parse the dom after the class is added?

Any help would be great, cheers!

EDIT:
I have a more complicated example

```
$('.accordion h3').not('.ui-state-active').find('a').live('hover', function(){
```

Where the `ui-state-active` class is added dynamically. bitsMix has pointed out that this code is making the `a` live. So I've updated it to

```
$('.accordion h3').live('hover', function(){
  $(this).not('.ui-state-active').find('a').stop().animate({
```

and it works! Thanks guys!

Comment: ｀$('.accordion h3').not('.ui-state-active').find('a').live('hover',function()｀ would `live` the `hover` to `a`, not `h3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add live to the like this:

```
$('.block.grey').live( "hover",function(){
    $(this).css('margin-left', '10px');    
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7E6vG/3/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.grey').live('hover',function(){
    $(this).css('margin-left', '100px');    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bitsmix/7E6vG/2/ live demo :)

Answer (score 2):

Here it comes:

```
$('.block').hover(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', '#CCC'); 
    $(this).addClass('grey');
});

$('.block.grey').live('hover',function(){
    $(this).css('margin-left', '10px');    
});
```

[jQuery Live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
$('.block.grey').live('hover', function() {
    $(this).css('margin-left', '10px');    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7E6vG/1/